# Rewrite url service.php?p_id=1&s_id=4 to service/seo

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url in the form of:

```
http://example.com/service.php?p_id=1&s_id=4
```

The question now is:

How can I turn that `id` value `1&4` to be `seo`? (`1&4` is representing `seo` in mysql database). How can we retrieve it turn it to something like that.

```
http://example.com/service/seo/
```

Please guide me on this one, I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing your [permalink settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)?

Comment: No because this time i m not using word press....i want to make this via mod_rewrite

Comment: Is `/service.php?p_id=1&s_id=4` not a WP page/post?

Comment: OK, I've removed the WordPress tag so there's no confusion.

Comment: Can you post your present code from .htaccess

Comment: no /service.php?p_id=1&s_id=4 is not a WP page/post

Comment: the htaccess code is not deciding by me for a dynamic rewrite....so that if the id's change then the title(seo) changes automatically...:(

Comment: anybody has the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this rule as your **first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /service\.php\?s_id=([^&\s]+)&p_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /service/%1/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^service/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ service.php?s_id=$1&p_id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: i want to tell you that the following url is created something like <a href="services.php?s_id=<?php echo $fetch['s_menu_id']; ?>&amp;p_id=<?php echo $fetch['s_menu_parent'] ?>">

Comment: how can i make this link seo friendly please guide me

Comment: Every `s_id` and `p_id` will need to have its own seo friendly URL. Check updated answer above.

Comment: i can convert the s_id=2to(respected title stored in data base) if the url services/2/2 redirects to the destination.......

Comment: Recently i put the following rule to the live .htaccess on the hosting nd found no css and js loaded please just click on the link http://www.magickeyinfotech.com/services/2/2/

Comment: i think we have to created a rule for the directories like css,js,... to load them....

Comment: No not the rule problem is how you are including css, js etc. Your correct path is `http://www.magickeyinfotech.com/css/stylesheet.css` which should be included as `<link href="/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` Basically use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. **As an alternative** you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: you are right ,the problem was in the paths....now i will have to change all paths in the project ......and i would like to say a warm thanks .......

Comment: Please do me a single favour more plz...if i have to rewrite rule for  magickeyinfotech.com/2/2 ...post the appropriate rule..

Comment: Will that also be rewritten to `/service.php?s_id=1&p_id=2` ?

Comment: I asked you a question in my previous comment if you notice. And bear in mind SO questions are for solving one particular problem. Asking new question from comments is usually discouraged here.